# removing greyscale css filter from images with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, filter, setinterval

I'm trying to cycle through some images and remove a filter from them one at a time.

```
var h = 0;

function removeGreyscale() {
  document.images[h].style.webkitfilter = "grayscale(0)";
  document.images[h].style.filter = "grayscale(0)";
  h += 1;
  if (h === 8) {
    h = 0;
  }
}

setInterval(removeGreyscale, 3000);
```

This code is currently not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you need to capitalize the 'f' in the `webkitFilter` property:

```
document.images[h].style.webkitFilter = "grayscale(1)";
document.images[h].style.filter = "grayscale(1)";
```

Chrome [still requires](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) the `-webkit` prefix for the [`filter` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter), but it should have already worked in Firefox.

---

If you want to loop over the elements and remove the filter from the current element and add it back to the previous element, then you can use the following:

- `i % images.length` - This will get the index of the current element and then reset back to `0` when `i` exceeds the number of images.
- `(curr - 1 < 0 ? images.length : curr) - 1` - Likewise, this will get the previous element by subtracting `1` from the current index or `1` from the total number of images if the index is `-1`.

It would obviously be better to add/remove/toggle classes here and avoid inline styling, but nonetheless, this works for example purposes:

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img'),
    i = 0;

function removeGreyscale() {
  var curr = i % images.length,
      prev = (curr - 1 < 0 ? images.length : curr) - 1;
      
  // Remove grayscale filter from the current element
  images[curr].style.webkitFilter = "grayscale(0)";
  images[curr].style.filter = "grayscale(0)";
  
  // Add grayscale filter to the previous element
  images[prev].style.webkitFilter = "grayscale(1)";
  images[prev].style.filter = "grayscale(1)";
  i++;
}

setInterval(removeGreyscale, 1000);
```

```css
img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

```html
<img src="//placehold.it/200/f00" />
<img src="//placehold.it/200/0f0" />
<img src="//placehold.it/200/00f" />
```

Comment: Thank you! I've never tried using prefixed styles with Javascript before so was unsure about this. The code is now working though not how I had hoped. It is ungreyscaling my images one by one but then leaving them all ungreyscaled rather than only ever letting one be coloured/ungrey.

Comment: I have no idea how you worked that out but it looks perfect!

Answer (score 1):

CSS only solution: 
http://jsfiddle.net/t2zaf1fk/2/

HTML:

```
<img src="//placehold.it/200/f00" />
<img src="//placehold.it/200/0f0" />
<img src="//placehold.it/200/00f" />
```

CSS:

```
img {
    -webkit-animation: fade 3s linear 0 infinite;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);        
}
img:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-animation-delay:1s;
}
img:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay:2s
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    0% {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);    
    }
    65% {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);    
    }
    66% {
        -webkit-filter: none;    
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-filter: none;    
    }
}
```